# Rails not able to find ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using AWS Ubuntu 16.04.

I follow the steps in, and chose rbenv.
https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04

After installation, i do a git clone to get the rails project code. And then:

ubuntu@ip-172-31-17-168:~/web$ rails -v
Could not find globalid-0.4.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

I spent two days working on it, still can't fix it. I edit the Gemfile.lock. I find that there is version mismatch in many gems. The command "gem list --local" already shows gems are installed. But the version is mismatched.

I did a "bundle install", got another error

ubuntu@ip-172-31-25-85:~/web$ rails db:migrate
rails aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `default_options' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you might be missing the line

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
```

in your `Gemfile` which tells Bundler where to look for gems. Afaik rubygems.org should be available by default but it doesn't hurt to add it there. Otherwise please show the output of `bundle install` and `bundle update`.

Comment: the bundle install and bundle update output contains many lines. How to share it ?

Comment: i found. the root cause. Must have the file config/settings.yml. The default_options is defined in that file